# Python Pyqt5: Why string storage in QLineedit is different to standard python input()?

Tags: python, input, pyqt5, qlineedit

I want to read strings from a USB tag reader, this strings contains ascii chars. When use input() works good:

```
string=input("read: ")
read: 0100630414610870103BD0291724060124011537241422840
string
'0100630414610870103BD029\x1d1724060124011537241\x1d422840'
'\x1d' in string
True
```

If I use pyqt5 QLineEdit the special chars disappear:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout
class MiVentana(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()
    def init_ui(self):
        self.line_edit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.etiqueta = QLabel('Texto ingresado:', self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.etiqueta)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.line_edit.returnPressed.connect(self.actualizar_etiqueta)
        self.setWindowTitle('Ejemplo de QLineEdit')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)

    def actualizar_etiqueta(self):
        texto_ingresado = self.line_edit.text()
        self.etiqueta.setText('Texto ingresado: ' + texto_ingresado)
        texto_ingresado
        if '\xd1' not in texto_ingresado:
            print("missing chars")
        print(texto_ingresado)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventana = MiVentana()
    ventana.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
output:
missing chars
0100630414610870103BD0291724060124011537241422840
```

Python version is 3.11, PyQt5-5.15,  why QLineEdit remove the specials chars? who can I read all chars?

I try it in anothers PCs with the same result.

Comment: `\xd1` is not a printable or "type-able" character, so QLineEdit ignores it. You could try to subclass QLineEdit and override `keyPressEvent()`, then check for the event `text()` and compare it with `\xd1`.

Comment: The data from a USB tag reader will be ***unencoded bytes***, not text. If you want to use a line-edit as a user-interface, the simplest solution would be to use an escaped representation of the bytes in the line-edit, like this: `line_edit.setText( data.decode('unicode-escape'))`. Then to convert back to bytes, do: `data = line_edit.text().encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')`. Obviously, this means the user must enter all control-characters using textual escapes (such as "\x1d").